# Нужно дать имя файлу, которое определяется IP адресом и номером порта клиента

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет

Программирование сокетов. 
Нужно создать файл и записать там сообщение от сервера отправленное клиенту. Файл создается и сообщение там записывается(это работает). Нужно, чтобы файл создавался с именем, которое содержало номер порта и адрес(я не знаю как сделать).

код для клиента

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 1234))

msg = s.recv(1024)
print(msg.decode("utf-8"))

saveFile = open('{address}.txt','w')


saveFile.write(msg.decode("utf-8"))


saveFile.close()
```

### здесь файл создается   с именем {address} , а нужно чтобы был  IP адрес и номер порта клиента

```
saveFile = open('{address}.txt','w')


saveFile.write(msg.decode("utf-8"))


saveFile.close()
```

код сервера

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 1234))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f"Connection from {address} has been established!")
    clientsocket.send(bytes("Welcome to the server!", "utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 1234))
address, port = s.getpeername()
msg = s.recv(1024)
print(msg.decode("utf-8"))

saveFile = open(f'{address}_{port}.txt','w')


saveFile.write(msg.decode("utf-8"))


saveFile.close()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за  помощь. Не могу пока +1 поставить из-за рейтинга.  Поставила галочку